# Error while programming an adder with modelsim in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

Error:  C:/Users/username/dir1/dir2/sumador_modelo.vhd(11): near "NOT": (vcom-1576) expecting ')'.

Error: C:/Users/username/dir1/dir2/sumador_modelo.vhd(12): VHDL Compiler exiting.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY sumador_modelo IS
   PORT (a,b,Cin:IN STD_LOGIC; sum,Cout:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END sumador_modelo;

ARCHITECTURE sumador_modelo_flujo OF sumador_modelo IS
    BEGIN   
    sum<=(NOT a AND NOT b AND Cin) OR (NOT  a AND b AND NOT Cin) OR (a AND NOT b AND NOT Cin) OR (a AND b AND Cin); 
    Cout<=(NOT a AND b AND Cin) OR (a AND NOT b AND Cin) OR (a AND b NOT Cin) OR (a AND b AND Cin);
END sumador_modelo_flujo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an "and" before the not in the expression for Cout:

```
sum<=(NOT a AND NOT b AND Cin) OR (NOT  a AND b AND NOT Cin) OR (a AND NOT b AND NOT Cin) OR (a AND b AND Cin); 
Cout<=(NOT a AND b AND Cin) OR (a AND NOT b AND Cin) OR (a AND b and NOT Cin) OR (a AND b AND Cin);
```

This can be confusing to debug. So what you do is comment out the whole expression and investigate it in pieces to find the error.  So, for your expression:

-- Step 1:

```
Cout<=(NOT a AND b AND Cin) ;
```

-- Step 2, first worked, so add another piece:

```
Cout<=(NOT a AND b AND Cin) OR (a AND NOT b AND Cin) ;
```

-- Step 3, previous worked, so add another piece:

```
Cout<=(NOT a AND b AND Cin) OR (a AND NOT b AND Cin) OR (a AND b NOT Cin) ;
```

Ah, now we have an error.  Hence, the issue is in the third expression.  Now investigate the third expression and you can more readily see the bug

Comment: For a one time PAL using HW guy it might seem natural to describe AND OR arrays as AND term lines joined by ORs. Inserting newlines after each OR allows the analyzer (here vcom) to localize the problem to an AND term line. An old time PAL programmer might also think to line up the terms on successive lines using spaces where no NOT inversions occur. The problem would be noticed during design entry. This is a syntax error not matching the BNF from IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.1 General where the expression is expected to be bounded by a closing parenthese.

Comment: @user1155120  I suspect some tools will indeed do better error reporting when you split your expression across lines, however, do all of them do that?   Certainly some are better than others.

Comment: Syntax errors are detected prior to determining semantic meaning. The line number and character position of a non-matching lexical element can be available (ghdl, nvc, etc.). However relating descent through intermediary expression BNF targets could take pages. The reason for a syntax error can't always fit in an error message for a typographical error. Here Modelsim will convey the line number and with near "NOT" localize the error with the creative use of white space, also enhancing readability.

Comment: Vantage once had a tool that demonstrated BNF matching. It was both too slow and a bit dear compared to the price of Modelsim in 1991. Expressions are complex enough showing that wouldn't have mean much to the average language user without requiring in depth knowledge. Using newlines and lining up an terms with space for NOT would also point out the missing AND. The Cout terms are not optimal here either -  `(A and B)  or (A and Cin) or (B and Cin)` is more succinct noting for both we can trust synthesis to optimize.

Comment: Notice all three give snippets of the reason for the error. [Creative use of white space to localize Modelsim error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSZ8D.jpg).

Comment: @user1155120  Anything that makes it more clear is good style in my mind.   However, I would hate to imply that a tool always get this right.   I used Vantage on a project.   If the ports mismatched in size, then core dump - no errors.   That was fun to debug.

Comment: Vantage VSS died an ignominious death, steam rolled first by by -1993. The separate syntax could sure fill a screen full BNF expansions (and you couldn't copy and paste the output). Note all three tools here agreed NOT didn't belong there.